# FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an email account in firebase in my `register` function, and then creating a `profile` collection to store profile information such as profile image, firstName, lastName, etc.

Currently, I receive this error when I click on the register button:

> FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined```

I believe this is happening because firebase hasn't created the `users` collection  fast enough and when I try to create the `profile` collection, it renders the error because it can't locate the users collection.

Should I be using an async function?

```js
function Register() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");

  const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((auth) => {
        // it successfully created a new user with email and password
        if (auth) {
          history.push("/dashboard");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));

    db.collection("users").doc(user?.uid).collection("profile").add({
      image: image,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      username: username,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the line of code where you call doc():

```
db.collection("users").doc(user?.uid).collection("profile").add({
```

Note that you are *possibly* passing undefined to `doc()`.  That will happen if `user` is null or undefined.  This is likely because `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is asynchronous and doesn't complete immediately.  If you want to do something after the account is created, you should do that within your `then` callback.

```
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((credential) => {
        db.collection("users").doc(credential.user.uid).collection("profile").add({
          image: image,
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          username: username,
        });
        history.push("/dashboard");
      })
```

Comment: Thank you, Doug! Just read up on async functions and you're totally right. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!